# Use variable in randint argument

Tags: python, string, int, concatenation

Total beginner here,

I'm writing a program that rolls dice for the user, and I want it to be able to change the number of faces of the die per user input. I can't seem to get the variable     amount_faces     to work as an     int    for the     randint()    function, I get a "TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objetcts" error everytime:

```
from sys import exit
from random import randint

def start():
    print "Would you like to roll a dice?"
    choice = raw_input(">")
    if "yes" in choice:
        roll()
    elif "no" in choice:
        exit()
    else:
        print "I can't understand that, try again."
        start()

def roll():
    print "How many faces does the die have?"
    amount_faces = raw_input(">")
    if amount_faces is int:
        print "The number of faces has to be an integer, try again."
        roll()
    else:            
        print "Rolling die...."
        int(amount_faces)
        face = randint(1,*amount_faces)
        print "You have rolled %s" % face
        exit()

start()
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int(amount_faces)` does not change `amount_faces` in-place. You need to assign the integer object the function returns:

```
amount_faces = int(amount_faces)
```

`amount_faces` is not an iterable, so you cannot use the `*arg` syntax here:

```
face = randint(1,*amount_faces)
```

You'll have to remove the `*`:

```
face = randint(1, amount_faces)
```

You are also not testing for integers correctly here:

```
if amount_faces is int:
```

`int` is a type object, `amount_faces` is just a string. You can catch the `ValueError` thrown by `int()` to detect that the input was not convertible, instead:

```
while True:
    amount_faces = raw_input(">")
    try:
        amount_faces = int(amount_faces)
    except ValueError:
        print "The number of faces has to be an integer, try again."
    else:
        break

print "Rolling die...."
face = randint(1, amount_faces)
print "You have rolled %s" % face
```

You probably want to check out [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response) and not use recursion for program control.